# Си Удаление элемента в doubly Linkedlist

Tags: c, алгоритм, указатели, двусвязный-список

проблема с удалением элемента в листе. То есть когда элемент в листе только один, я использую функцию delete_last, где если остался 1 элемент, выполняется else if (head->next == NULL). Но элемент не удаляется и присваивает непонятные значения. И после попытки добавить один элемент, выводит его значения неограниченное количество раз.

Сама функция delete_last работает, но только до последнего оставшегося элемента.
Пожалуйста помогите, никак не могу исправить ошибку

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define NAME_SIZE   256

    int ml_bits = 0, fr_bits = 0;
    int ml_amount = 0, fr_amount = 0;

    // structure for one node in the linked list
    typedef struct node_struct {
        int age;
        char name[NAME_SIZE];
        struct node_struct *next;
        struct node_struct *prev;
    } Node;

    // enumerated type for valid operations
    typedef enum operation_enum {
        NEW = 1, FIND, DISPLAY_ASC, DISPLAY_DESC, DELETE_LAST, SHOW_MEMORY, QUIT
    } Operation;

    //
    // function prototypes for the functions the students need to create
    //

    void insert_node(Node **head_ptr, Node *node){
        system("cls");

        Node *current = *head_ptr;
        node->next = NULL;
        if (current == NULL){
            printf("(Node Inserted)\n");
            node->prev = NULL;
            *head_ptr = node;
        }
        else{
            while (current->next != NULL){
                current = current->next;
            }
            printf("(Not First)(Node Inserted)\n");
            current->next = node;
            node->prev = current;
        }
    }

    Node *find_node(Node *head, const int age){
        while (head != NULL){
            if (head->age == age){
                return head;
            }
            head = head->next;
        }
        system("cls");
        printf("Your node not found\n");
        return 0;
    }
    void display_node(Node *node){
        system("cls");
        printf("(Found node)\n");
        printf("Name: %sAge: %d\n", node->name, node->age);
        printf("(Found node)\n");
    }
    void display_reverse(Node* head){
        Node *temp = head;
        if (temp == NULL){
            return;
        }
        while (temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        while (temp != NULL){
            printf("\nName: %sAge: %d\n", temp->name, temp->age);
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
    }

    void display_list(Node *head, Operation op){
        system("cls");
        switch(op){
            case DISPLAY_DESC:
                printf("(Display reverse)");
                display_reverse(head);
                printf("(Display reverse)\n");
                break;
            case DISPLAY_ASC:
                printf("(Display ascending)");
                while (head != NULL){
                    printf("\nName: %sAge: %d\n", head->name, head->age);
                    head = head->next;
                }
                printf("(Display ascending)\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    void show_memory(){
        system("cls");
        printf("(Malloc)\n");
        printf("Currently used memory in bits: %d\nCurrently used amount of memory: %d\n", ml_bits, ml_amount);

        printf("\n(Free)\n");
        printf("Deleted memory in bits: %d\nDeleted memory in amount: %d\n\n", fr_bits, fr_amount);
    }

    void Memory_up(Node* temp){
        ml_bits = ml_bits + (sizeof(temp));
        ml_amount++;
    }

    void Memory_down(Node *temp){
        fr_amount++;
        fr_bits = fr_bits + sizeof(temp);
        ml_amount--;
        ml_bits = ml_bits - sizeof(temp);
    }

    void delete_last(Node *head){
        system("cls");
        Node *temp = head;
        if (head == NULL){
            printf("Empty list\n");
        }
        else if (head->next == NULL){
            head = head->next;
            printf("deleted_name: %sdeleted_age: %d\n", temp->name, temp->age);
            free(temp);

        }
        else{
            printf("(Delete last)\n");
            while (temp->next->next != NULL){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            Memory_down(temp->next);
            printf("deleted_name: %sdeleted_age: %d\n", temp->next->name, temp->next->age);
            free(temp->next);
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    /*
     * Create a new node.  The "next" member is initialized to NULL, other members are
     * set according to the parameters.
     *
     * Parameters:
     *      in: age - the value to store in the age field of the node
     *      in: name - the name to store in the name field of the node
     *
     * Returns a pointer to a Node.  Node.next is intialized to NULL
     */
    Node *new_node(const int age, const char *name)
    {
        Node *new = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (!new) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for new node\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        new->age = age;
        strncpy(new->name, name, NAME_SIZE);
        new->next = NULL;
        Memory_up(new);
        return new;
    }

    /*
     * Get user input including an operation and data associated with that operation, if any.
     *
     * Parameters:
     *      out: operation - the operation the user wants
     *      out: age if the operation was insert or find, else undefined
     *      out: name if the operation was insert or find, else undefined
     *
     * The name parameter must be a pointer to memory sufficiently large to hold NAME_SIZE
     * characters (including null character at the end).
     *
     * Returns: false if success, else true
     */
    bool get_operation(Operation *operation, int *age, char *name)
    {
        const char prompt[] = "Enter an option:\n\t1) Add node\n\t2) Find node\n\t3) display ascending\n\t4) display descending\n\t5) delete last\n\t6) show memory\n\t7) Quit\n-> ";
        char input[NAME_SIZE];

        bool invalid_operation = true;
        while (invalid_operation) {

            fprintf(stdout, prompt);

            // get the option number from the user's input
            int op;
            if (fgets(input, NAME_SIZE, stdin) && sscanf(input, "%d", &op) == 1) {
                *operation = op;
                switch(op) {
                    case NEW:
                        // Need both age and name
                        fprintf(stdout, "Age: ");
                        if (!fgets(input, NAME_SIZE, stdin) || sscanf(input, "%d", age) != 1) {
                            system("cls");
                            fprintf(stdout, "Age must be an integer\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        fprintf(stdout, "Name: ");
                        if (!fgets(name, NAME_SIZE, stdin)) {
                            system("cls");
                            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading name from stdin\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        invalid_operation = false;
                        break;

                    case FIND:
                        // Only need age
                        fprintf(stdout, "Age: ");
                        if (!fgets(input, NAME_SIZE, stdin) || sscanf(input, "%d", age) != 1) {
                            system("cls");
                            fprintf(stdout, "Age must be an integer\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        invalid_operation = false;
                        break;

                    case DISPLAY_ASC:
                    case DISPLAY_DESC:
                        // no additional information needed
                        invalid_operation = false;
                        break;
                    case DELETE_LAST:
                        invalid_operation = false;
                        break;
                    case SHOW_MEMORY:
                        invalid_operation = false;
                        break;
                    case QUIT:
                        return true;

                    default:
                        system("cls");
                        fprintf(stdout, "Invalid option\n\n");
                        break;
                } // end switch
            } else {
                system("cls");
                fprintf(stdout, "Invalid option\n");
            }
        } // end while

        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Repeatedly prompt the user for an operation and perform the operation.
     *
     * Parameters: n/a
     *
     * Returns:
     *      0 on success, else 1
     */
    void main(){
        Node *head = NULL;      // pointer to the first node in the linked list
        Node *node;
        Operation op;
        int age;
        char name[NAME_SIZE];

        while (!get_operation(&op, &age, name)) {

            switch(op) {
                case NEW:
                    // Create a new node and insert it into the list
                    node = new_node(age, name);
                    insert_node(&head, node);
                    break;

                case FIND:
                    // Display all nodes containing the specified age
                    node = find_node(head, age);
                    while(node && node->age == age) {
                        display_node(node);
                        node = node->next;
                    }
                    break;

                case DISPLAY_ASC:
                    display_list(head, op);
                    break;
                case DISPLAY_DESC:
                    // Display the entire linked list in the specified order
                    display_list(head, op);
                    break;
                case DELETE_LAST:
                    delete_last(head);
                    break;
                case SHOW_MEMORY:
                    show_memory();
                    break;
                case QUIT:
                    return 0;

                default: break;// don't need, but here to avoid compiler warning
            } // end switch
        } // end while

        // if we get here, it's because there was an error reading input
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В метод `delete_last` вы должны передавать указатель на указатель на головной узел списка. Иначе функция будет иметь дело с копией указателя на головной узел, а исходный указатель на головной узел не будет изменен.

Ниже представлена минимальная демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как в принципе может быть реализован данный метод.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_SIZE   256

typedef struct node_struct 
{
    int age;
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    struct node_struct *next;
    struct node_struct *prev;
} Node;

void insert_node( Node **head_ptr, Node *node )
{
    Node *prev_ptr = NULL;

    while ( *head_ptr != NULL )
    {
        prev_ptr = *head_ptr;
        head_ptr = &( *head_ptr )->next;
    }

    *head_ptr = node;
    node->prev = prev_ptr;
    node->next = NULL;
}

void delete_last( Node **head_ptr )
{
    if ( *head_ptr )
    {
        while ( ( *head_ptr )->next != NULL ) head_ptr = &( *head_ptr )->next;

        Node *temp = *head_ptr;
        *head_ptr = ( *head_ptr )->next;

        free( temp );
    }
}

void display_list( Node **head_ptr )
{
    for ( ; *head_ptr != NULL; head_ptr = &( *head_ptr )->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *head_ptr )->age );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *head = NULL;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        Node *node_ptr = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
        node_ptr->age = i;

        insert_node( &head, node_ptr );
    }

    display_list( &head );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        delete_last( &head );
        display_list( &head );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 
0 1 
0
```